# How to append to each element?

Tags: jquery

```
var form_error = jQuery('<div/>').attr('class', 'input-error').append(jQuery('<div/>').attr('class', 'error-label'));
var registration_fields_list = jQuery('<ul/>');

jQuery.each(registration_fields, function(){
    var label = jQuery('<label/>').text(this.label);
    var field = null;

    field = jQuery('<input/>').attr({'name': this.input_name, 'class': this.input_class, 'type': (typeof this.type != 'undefined' ? this.type : 'text')});

    console.log(jQuery('<li/>').append(label, field, form_error));
});
```

I cant find the problem, but the thing is that `form_error` appends only to the last `li`, not to each. Where i am wrong?

Comment: Did you read the doco? If you `.append()` an existing element to a single parent (which is what you're doing) it will be _moved,_ not _copied._ (Also, your code as shown doesn't seem to ever actually add anything to the DOM, it just creates new elements. And what is the `registration_fields` variable passed to `.each()`? Should it be `registration_fields_list`?)

Comment: You create 1 (one) <ul>-element, so when you go through each of the created elements (which is one), the console log will only show 1  row.

Comment: I think you're trying to apply it to the ul instead of the li element?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new form_error element everytime you want to append it, since .append() doesn't clone existing elemets.

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)

http://api.jquery.com/append/